# Go grep command clone

Tags: regex, go, concurrency, search

I am trying to make a simple clone of the command line utility **grep**. I'm working on it just for fun and to practice Go. The thing is, I am trying to make it in a way that if several files are given at the command line, a different goroutine is generated to speed up the process. Even so, standard grep still gets results faster by an amount of around 60% less processing time.

Here it is the code for it. Can you please provide some opinions about it?

```
package main


import (

    "bufio"

    "flag"

    "fmt"

    "io"

    "os"

    "path/filepath"

    "regexp"

    "sync"

)


type result struct {

    Filename string

    Line string

    LineNumber int

    Error error

}


var strRex string

var filenames []string

var regRex *regexp.Regexp

var wg sync.WaitGroup

var allResults []result

var verbose = false

var recursive string

var recursiveFileList []string

var fileFilter string

var rexfileFilter *regexp.Regexp

var inverseSearch bool


func init() {

    var rexError error

    flag.StringVar(&strRex, "r", "", "Regular expresion to match against the input files")

    flag.BoolVar(&verbose, "v", false, "It sets verbose output (Basically showing filename and line number for each match)")

    flag.BoolVar(&inverseSearch, "i", false, "It does what you might expect.. reverse the search")

    flag.StringVar(&recursive, "R", "", "Recursively find all files starting from the current folder and apply the given search to them")

    flag.StringVar(&fileFilter, "FF", "", "Filter to be applied to the filenames when used recursevily")

    flag.Parse()

    if strRex == "" {

        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "The '-r' (regular expression flag is mandatory)\n")

        os.Exit(1)

    }

    regRex, rexError = regexp.Compile(strRex)

    if rexError != nil {

        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Your regex '%s' cant compile. Error : %s", strRex, rexError.Error())

        os.Exit(2)

    }

    rexfileFilter, rexError = regexp.Compile(fileFilter)

    if rexError != nil {

        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Your regex '%s' cant compile. Error : %s", rexfileFilter, rexError.Error())

        os.Exit(3)

    }

    if recursive != "" {

        var err error

        filenames, err = walkDir(recursive)

        if err != nil {

            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%s", err.Error())

        }


    } else {


        filenames = flag.Args()

    }


}


func main() {


    stat, err := os.Stdin.Stat()

    if err != nil {

        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "There is an error reading from stdin : %s", err)

        os.Exit(3)

    }

    if (stat.Mode() & os.ModeNamedPipe) != 0 {

        grepStdin(os.Stdin, regRex)

    } else {

        chResults := make(chan *result, 4)

        wg.Add(len(filenames))

        for _, fn := range filenames {

            go grep(fn, regRex, &wg, chResults)

        }

        go func(wait *sync.WaitGroup, ch chan<- *result) {

            wg.Wait()

            close(ch)

        }(&wg, chResults)


        for res := range chResults {

            if verbose {

                formatRes(res, 1)

            } else {

                formatRes(res, 2)

            }


        }

    }

}


func grepStdin(ptr io.Reader, reg *regexp.Regexp) {

    bf := bufio.NewScanner(ptr)

    var lineno = 1


    for bf.Scan() {

        // There is no XOR in Golang, so you ahve to do this :

        if line := bf.Text(); (reg.Match([]byte(line)) && !inverseSearch) || (!reg.Match([]byte(line)) && inverseSearch) {


            formatRes(&result{

                Line: line,

                LineNumber: lineno,

                Error: nil,

            }, 3)

        }

        lineno++

    }

}


func grep(file string, reg *regexp.Regexp, wait *sync.WaitGroup, ch chan<- *result) {

    fd, err := os.Open(file)

    if err != nil {

        ch <- &result{

            Filename: file,

            Error: err,

        }

    }

    bf := bufio.NewScanner(fd)

    var lineno = 1


    for bf.Scan() {

        // There is no XOR in Golang, so you ahve to do this :

        if line := bf.Text(); (reg.Match([]byte(line)) && !inverseSearch) || (!reg.Match([]byte(line)) && inverseSearch) {


            ch <- &result{

                Filename: file,

                Line: line,

                LineNumber: lineno,

                Error: nil,

            }

        }

        lineno++

    }

    wg.Done()

}


func formatRes(r *result, format int) {

    if format == 1 {

        if r.Error == nil {

            fmt.Printf("%d - %s - %s\n", r.LineNumber, r.Filename, r.Line)

        } else {

            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%s - %s \n", r.Filename, r.Error)

        }

    }

    if format == 2 {

        if r.Error == nil {

            fmt.Printf("%s\n", r.Line)

        } else {

            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%s - %s \n", r.Filename, r.Error)

        }

    }

    if format == 3 {

        if r.Error == nil {

            fmt.Printf("%s\n", r.Line)

        } else {

            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%s\n", r.Error)

        }

    }

}


func walkDir(path string) ([]string, error) {

    list := make([]string, 0, 50)

    err := filepath.Walk(".",

        func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {

            if err != nil {

                return err

            }

            if fileFilter != "" {

                if rexfileFilter.Match([]byte(filepath.Base(path))) {

                    list = append(list, path)

                }

            } else {

                list = append(list, path)

            }

            return nil // Unreachable code

        })

    if err != nil {

        return nil, err

    }

    return list, nil

}
```

Comment: Code must be correct. To be sure that code is correct, code must be readable. I find your double-spaced code to be unreadable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if line := bf.Text(); (reg.Match([]byte(line)) && !inverseSearch) || (!reg.Match([]byte(line)) && inverseSearch) {
```

As in other C-like languages, golang [evaluates binary logical operators conditionally left-to-right](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Logical_operators). As written, the program is often going to evaluate the reg.Match() twice, because it appears twice and in each subexpression it is tested before `inverseSearch`. As this is the program's most expensive operation, that's significant for performance.

```
if line := bf.Text(); (!inverseSearch && reg.Match([]byte(line))) || (inverseSearch && !reg.Match([]byte(line))) {
```

should avoid the double evaluation. Or write an xor helper function.

Other things:

Don't test for stdin being usable if you aren't reading from it. It's common for programs executing a program in a subprocess to close filehandles that the program shouldn't need to use. In other words `/bin/grep foo filename <&-` works, your `./grep -r foo filename <&-` does not and should.

Rewrite/replace grepStdin() so that it reuses grep(). Nobody likes having the algorithm implemented twice in the same program. You can use /dev/stdin as a filename for stdin on *nix; or, keep the file opening part separate and have a common function for grepping over the opened file handle used by both codepaths.

The `format` parameter to formatRes uses magic constant values that one has to read its implementation to understand. It would be better to replace it with `verbose bool` so the verbose flag can be passed directly and its meaning is then obvious. The stdin case would be better not to treat specially here also.

Answer (score 6):

> The thing is, even so, standard grep still gets results faster by an amount of 60 % less processing time

For more information on what makes GNU grep fast, read [this](https://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-current/2010-August/019310.html) by the original author.

---

Here is some feedback on writing idiomatic Go.

### Lines

Your code is oddly formatted.

It is very uncommon to have empty lines everywhere. In your code, empty lines more than double the length of your code. In most cases, I only add extra lines to separate functions, structs, if statements, for loops, etc.

```
package main


import (
    "bufio"

    "flag"

    "fmt"

    "io"

    "os"

    "path/filepath"

    "regexp"

    "sync"

)


type result struct {

    Filename string

    Line string

    LineNumber int

    Error error

}
```

Becomes:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "regexp"
    "sync"
)


type result struct {
    Filename string
    Line string
    LineNumber int
    Error error
}
```

### Line length

Keep lines to a length of 80 characters. It makes code easier to read on smaller monitors or if you split your screen to view multiple things.

```
flag.StringVar(&strRex, "r", "", "Regular expresion to match against the input files")

flag.BoolVar(&verbose, "v", false, "It sets verbose output (Basically showing filename and line number for each match)")

flag.BoolVar(&inverseSearch, "i", false, "It does what you might expect.. reverse the search")

flag.StringVar(&recursive, "R", "", "Recursively find all files starting from the current folder and apply the given search to them")

flag.StringVar(&fileFilter, "FF", "", "Filter to be applied to the filenames when used recursevily")
```

Becomes:

```
flag.StringVar(&strRex, "r", "",
    "Regular expresion to match against the input files")

flag.BoolVar(&verbose, "v", false,
    "It sets verbose output (Basically showing filename and line number "+
    "for each match)")

flag.BoolVar(&inverseSearch, "i", false,
    "It does what you might expect.. reverse the search")

flag.StringVar(&recursive, "R", "",
    "Recursively find all files starting from the current folder and "+
    "apply the given search to them")

flag.StringVar(&fileFilter, "FF", "",
    "Filter to be applied to the filenames when used recursevily")
```

### Use a C-style for loop

In `grepStdin()` you initialize `lineno`, increment it and only use it in the for loop. That's a standard for loop. Once inside the for loop, we can rename it to `l` because it's purpose is clear from it's usage.

```
var lineno = 1

for bf.Scan() {
    // There is no XOR in Golang, so you ahve to do this:
    if line := bf.Text(); (reg.Match([]byte(line)) && !inverseSearch) || (!reg.Match([]byte(line)) && inverseSearch) {
        formatRes(&result{
            Line: line,
            LineNumber: lineno,
            Error: nil,
        }, 3)
    }
    lineno++
}
```

Becomes:

```
for l := 1; bf.Scan(); l++ {
    // There is no XOR in Golang, so you ahve to do this:
    if line := bf.Text(); (reg.Match([]byte(line)) && !inverseSearch) || (!reg.Match([]byte(line)) && inverseSearch) {
        formatRes(&result{
            Line:       line,
            LineNumber: l,
            Error:      nil,
        }, 3)
    }
}
```

### Combine multiple `var` declarations

You can combine multiple variables declared with `var` as such:

```
var strRex string

var filenames []string

var regRex *regexp.Regexp

var wg sync.WaitGroup

var allResults []result

var verbose = false

var recursive string

var recursiveFileList []string

var fileFilter string

var rexfileFilter *regexp.Regexp

var inverseSearch bool
```

Becomes:

```
var (
    strRex            string
    filenames         []string
    regRex            *regexp.Regexp
    wg                sync.WaitGroup
    allResults        []result
    verbose           = false
    recursive         string
    recursiveFileList []string
    fileFilter        string
    rexfileFilter     *regexp.Regexp
    inverseSearch     bool
)
```

This is far more readable.

### Use `log` to write to standard error

You can utilize the `log` package to print (possibly fatal) errors to standard error.

```
fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr,
    "The '-r' (regular expression flag is mandatory)\n")

os.Exit(1)
```

Becomes:

```
if strRex == "" {
    log.Fatalln("The regular expression flag '-r' is mandatory")
}
```

And

```
if rexError != nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Your regex '%s' cant compile. Error : %s", strRex, rexError.Error())
    os.Exit(2)

}
```

Becomes:

```
if rexError != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Your regex '%s' cant compile. Error : %s\n", strRex,
        rexError)
}
```

Notice that you don't need to call `Error()` to get the string from it.

By doing this, you won't get custom return values. I don't think they're very useful in lieu of a good error message.

### Combine if and assignment

```
var err error

filenames, err = walkDir(recursive)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%s", err.Error())
}
```

Becomes:

```
var err error

if filenames, err = walkDir(recursive); err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

### Move things out of the global scope

Your `wg` wait group is in the global scope. It doesn't need to be. You already pass `wait` to `grep()`, so use it.

`allResults` is never used. `recursiveFileList` is never used.

We can also move all of your flag variables to a common `struct`. This is just a preference, but it tells readers what is a flag and what isn't.

### Use a switch statement

In `formatRes` you can use a switch statement instead of multiple if statements.

You can also clean up how you print things, like using `Println` instead of `Printf`.

```
switch format {
case 1:
    if r.Error == nil {
        fmt.Printf("%d - %s - %s\n", r.LineNumber, r.Filename, r.Line)
    } else {
        log.Printf("%s - %s\n", r.Filename, r.Error)
    }
    break
case 2:
    if r.Error == nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", r.Line)
    } else {
        log.Printf("%s - %s\n", r.Filename, r.Error)
    }
    break
case 3:
    if r.Error == nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", r.Line)
    } else {
        log.Println(r.Error)
    }
}
```

### Move your condition to a separate function

Your condition

```
(reg.Match([]byte(line)) && !fl.inverseSearch) || (!reg.Match([]byte(line)) && fl.inverseSearch)
```

Is long, and as Colin points out, you can take advantage of short circuiting.

Go does not provide XOR, but [it doesn't need to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23025720/6789498). I'll leave that for you to implement.

We can define a function as such:

```
func match(reg *regexp.Regexp, line string) bool {
    return !fl.inverseSearch && reg.Match([]byte(line)) || (fl.inverseSearch && !reg.Match([]byte(line)))
}
```

### Use `grepStdin()` in `grep()`

As Colin says, they contain duplicate code. I'll leave that for you to implement.

### Conclusion

There are many other places to clean up the code, but I think you'll get the gist. Here is the final code I ended up with:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "regexp"
    "sync"
)

type result struct {
    Filename   string
    Line       string
    LineNumber int
    Error      error
}

type flags struct {
    strRex        string
    recursive     string
    fileFilter    string
    verbose       bool
    inverseSearch bool
}

var (
    fl            flags
    filenames     []string
    regRex        *regexp.Regexp
    rexfileFilter *regexp.Regexp
)

func init() {
    dfl := flags{
        strRex:        "",
        verbose:       false,
        inverseSearch: false,
        recursive:     "",
        fileFilter:    "",
    }

    var rexError error

    flag.StringVar(&fl.strRex, "r", dfl.strRex,
        "Regular expresion to match against the input files")

    flag.StringVar(&fl.recursive, "R", dfl.recursive,
        "Recursively find all files starting from the current folder and "+
            "apply the given search to them")

    flag.StringVar(&fl.fileFilter, "FF", dfl.fileFilter,
        "Filter to be applied to the filenames when used recursevily")

    flag.BoolVar(&fl.verbose, "v", dfl.verbose,
        "It sets verbose output (Basically showing filename and line number "+
            "for each match)")

    flag.BoolVar(&fl.inverseSearch, "i", dfl.inverseSearch,
        "It does what you might expect.. reverse the search")

    flag.Parse()

    if fl.strRex == "" {
        log.Fatalln("The regular expression flag '-r' is mandatory")
    }

    regRex, rexError = regexp.Compile(fl.strRex)

    if rexError != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Your regex '%s' cant compile. Error : %s\n", fl.strRex,
            rexError)
    }

    rexfileFilter, rexError = regexp.Compile(fl.fileFilter)

    if rexError != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Your regex '%s' cant compile. Error : %s", rexfileFilter,
            rexError)
    }

    if fl.recursive != "" {
        var err error

        if filenames, err = walkDir(fl.recursive); err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
    } else {
        filenames = flag.Args()
    }
}

func main() {
    stat, err := os.Stdin.Stat()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("There is an error reading from stdin: %s", err)
    }

    var wait sync.WaitGroup

    if (stat.Mode() & os.ModeNamedPipe) != 0 {
        grepStdin(os.Stdin, regRex)
    } else {
        chResults := make(chan *result, 4)

        wait.Add(len(filenames))

        for _, fn := range filenames {
            go grep(fn, regRex, &wait, chResults)
        }

        go func(wait *sync.WaitGroup, ch chan<- *result) {
            wait.Wait()

            close(ch)
        }(&wait, chResults)

        for res := range chResults {
            if fl.verbose {
                formatRes(res, 1)
            } else {
                formatRes(res, 2)
            }
        }
    }
}

func match(reg *regexp.Regexp, line string) bool {
    return !fl.inverseSearch && reg.Match([]byte(line)) || (fl.inverseSearch && !reg.Match([]byte(line)))
}

func grepStdin(ptr io.Reader, reg *regexp.Regexp) {
    bf := bufio.NewScanner(ptr)

    for l := 1; bf.Scan(); l++ {
        if line := bf.Text(); match(reg, line) {
            formatRes(&result{
                Line:       line,
                LineNumber: l,
                Error:      nil,
            }, 3)
        }
    }
}

func grep(file string, reg *regexp.Regexp, wait *sync.WaitGroup,
    ch chan<- *result) {

    fd, err := os.Open(file)

    if err != nil {
        ch <- &result{
            Filename: file,
            Error:    err,
        }
    }

    bf := bufio.NewScanner(fd)

    for l := 1; bf.Scan(); l++ {
        if line := bf.Text(); match(reg, line) {
            ch <- &result{
                Filename:   file,
                Line:       line,
                LineNumber: l,
                Error:      nil,
            }
        }
    }

    wait.Done()
}

func formatRes(r *result, format int) {
    switch format {
    case 1:
        if r.Error == nil {
            fmt.Printf("%d - %s - %s\n", r.LineNumber, r.Filename, r.Line)
        } else {
            log.Printf("%s - %s\n", r.Filename, r.Error)
        }
        break
    case 2:
        if r.Error == nil {
            fmt.Println(r.Line)
        } else {
            log.Printf("%s - %s\n", r.Filename, r.Error)
        }
        break
    case 3:
        if r.Error == nil {
            fmt.Println(r.Line)
        } else {
            log.Println(r.Error)
        }
    }
}

func walkDir(path string) ([]string, error) {
    list := make([]string, 0, 50)

    err := filepath.Walk(".",
        func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }

            if fl.fileFilter != "" {
                if rexfileFilter.Match([]byte(filepath.Base(path))) {
                    list = append(list, path)
                }
            } else {
                list = append(list, path)
            }

            return nil
        })

    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return list, nil
}
```

In my opinion, it's far more readable and to-the-point.

Hope this helps!